# How to get the first word in the string

Tags: python, regex

text is :

```
WYATT    - Ranked # 855 with    0.006   %
XAVIER   - Ranked # 587 with    0.013   %
YONG     - Ranked # 921 with    0.006   %
YOUNG    - Ranked # 807 with    0.007   %
```

I want to get only

```
WYATT
XAVIER
YONG
YOUNG
```

I tried :

```
(.*)?[ ]
```

But it gives me the :

```
WYATT    - Ranked
```

Answer (score 189, accepted):

Regex is unnecessary for this.  Just use `some_string.split(' ', 1)[0]` or `some_string.partition(' ')[0]`.

Comment: Not if the words are separated by other characters (e.g. tabs).

Comment: As long as they are separated by the same character, it will work fine.  Just switch to `'\t'`.  True it won't work if  you have multiple delimiters, though even with 2 or 3 delimiters, it wouldn't be very difficult to use `split` or `partition` instead of regex.

Comment: `some_string.split(None, 1)[0]` will work if more than one space separates the first word.

Comment: Imagine you really want the first word without assuming it's the first item in the split array. Imagine my_string = "1 2 3 4 <> coolest". I have regexs for many things but not one that given that string would return "coolest". I don't thing suggesting split makes sense since "return first word" says nothing about the implied order of where that work may be in the list of words.

Comment: You can get the leftover string as well with `firstword, leftoverstring = some_string.split(' ', 1)`

Answer (score 33):

If you want to feel especially sly, you can write it as this:

```
(firstWord, rest) = yourLine.split(maxsplit=1)
```

This is supposed to bring the best from both worlds:

- optimality tweak with `maxsplit` while splitting with any whitespace
- improved reliability and readability, as [argued by the author of the technique](http://blog.ram.rachum.com/post/1198230058/python-idiom-for-taking-the-single-item-from-a).

I kind of fell in love with this solution and it's general unpacking capability, so I had to share it.

Comment: In python2 you may not be able to use the keyword argument, so you might want to go like `firstWord, rest = yourLine.split(None, 1)` loosing some readability though.

Comment: I like this, it's concise.  And if you don't want the rest of the line, you can use `(firstWord, *_) = yourLine.split(maxsplit=1)`.  Use `*_` instead of `_` because `split()` returns a variable number of arguments, according to the `maxsplit` parameter, and this will future-proof you.

Comment: @HuwWalters I don't see why protecting yourself with `*` when `maxsplit=1` is used, there is limited number of results.

Comment: Because it saves you from coding errors.  If you change the `maxsplit` value but fail to add an extra tuple element to unpack the extra value, as in `(firstWord, rest) = yourLine.split(maxsplit=2)`, you get `ValueError: too many values to unpack`.  An added bonus is that you don't create an unused variable `rest`.

Answer (score 17):

You shoud do something like :

```
print line.split()[0]
```

Comment: I agree. But small optimization tip: `print line.split(' ', 1)[0]`. This limits the split to the first word.

Comment: what does the "1" do here?

Comment: @algorythms Short circuits after finding the first split character, so you don't traverse the tail of the string.

Comment: @algorythms Here `1` is the `maxsplit` argument. There are some examples in the documentation to show how it works https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/split.html

Answer (score 11):

Use this regex

```
^\w+
```

---

`\w+` matches 1 to many characters.

`\w` is similar to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

`^` depicts the start of a string

---

**About Your Regex**

Your regex `(.*)?[ ]` should be `^(.*?)[ ]` or `^(.*?)(?=[ ])` if you don't want the space

Comment: You don't explain what functions to call and how when using this regex.

Answer (score 7):

Don't need a `regex`.
`string[: string.find(' ')]`

Comment: This is a bit more esoteric than `split` or `partition`, I think.  Do you get meaningful performance or memory gains this way?  You'd have to essentially iterate to the first instance of the token twice using this, but on the flip side, you wouldn't end up with the new tail string that you just throw away...

Comment: @sr2222 Yes, it has to iterate twice, but not thrue all the string.

Comment: Neither does `split` with a token limit or `partition`.

Comment: This approach is a nice optimization but it does not work well if the OP wants it to work when the first word is the entire string. If no spaces are found, `string.find` returns `-1`, removing the last character.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need regex to split a string on whitespace:

```
In [1]: text = '''WYATT    - Ranked # 855 with    0.006   %
   ...: XAVIER   - Ranked # 587 with    0.013   %
   ...: YONG     - Ranked # 921 with    0.006   %
   ...: YOUNG    - Ranked # 807 with    0.007   %'''

In [2]: print '\n'.join(line.split()[0] for line in text.split('\n'))
WYATT
XAVIER
YONG
YOUNG
```