# Save the first two words of each line

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file, 'description' which has the first column describing different attributes. I want to tell Python to just copy the first two words from each line. And then save the ***first two words*** in a new csv. I looked into the below link but could not get the result I was expecting.

[How to get the first word in the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750265/how-to-get-the-first-word-in-the-string)

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

with open('C:/Users/description.csv','r') as k:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
    print(" ".join(row.split(0)[:2]))
```

Error:

```
print(" ".join(row.split(0)[:2]))
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'


with open('thematchingresults.csv', 'w') as f:
    df.to_csv(f)
```

Comment: Your words, are not delimited by semicolons, so why are you expecting `delimiter=';'` to work? Also, `some_list[0]` will give you only the first element, not the first two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should solve your problem:

**For Python 3.x**

```
import csv

with open("input.csv", "r") as inp, open("output.csv", "w", newline='') as outp:
    reader = csv.reader(inp, delimiter=";")
    writer = csv.writer(outp, delimiter=";")
    for row in reader:
        first_col = row[0]
        first_two_words = " ".join(first_col.split(" ")[:2])
        # You can write more information if you need to.
        writer.writerow([first_two_words])
```

**For Python 2.7.x**

```
import csv

with open("input.csv", "r") as inp, open("output.csv", "wb") as outp:
    reader = csv.reader(inp, delimiter=";")
    writer = csv.writer(outp, delimiter=";")
    for row in reader:
        first_col = row[0]
        first_two_words = " ".join(first_col.split(" ")[:2])
        # You can write more information if you need to.
        writer.writerow([first_two_words])
```

Comment: Thanks Maurice, it throws out an error on newline. TypeError: 'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: I tried it with python 3.5 and it worked, which version are you using?

Comment: I am using Python 2.7.10.

Comment: Please try `open("output.csv", "wb")` for python 2.7 - can't test it at the moment, but according to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/csv.html#csv.writer) that should be the correct way to open the file

Answer (score 5):

just split your string, and join it back but keeping only the 2 first items:

```
s = "My girlfriend is a rich lady"
print(" ".join(s.split()[:2]))
```

result:

```
My girlfriend
```