# Cannot Get Python to Recognize Escape Tab Character

Tags: string, python-2.7, split, escaping

I'm new to Python and am having trouble with a seemingly simple objective. I've tried several methods for splitting a string by a tab character to no avail.

```
testStr = 'word1    word2'
    values = testStr.split("\t")
    print(values)
```

Results in

```
['word1    word2']
```

and

```
import re
testStr = 'word1    word2'
print(str(re.search(r'[^\t]', testStr).start()))
```

results in

```
0
```

Used the answers from the following posts:

[How to get the first word in the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750265/how-to-get-the-first-word-in-the-string)

[splitting a string based on tab in the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038426/splitting-a-string-based-on-tab-in-the-file)

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that your test string has a tab, and not spaces?  The two are represented differently.  I'd imagine a test string of `"word1\tword2"` would split correctly.

Comment: @roelofs You are correct. I thought that literally clicking tab when creating the string would be accounted for as \t.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `testStr` doesn't start with `\t`, so in the regexp pattern you do not need a `^`.

So in your case it will be:

```python
import re
testStr = 'word1\tword2'
print(str(re.search(r'[\t]', testStr).start()))
```

And the result will be

```
5
```