# Find first word in string Python

Tags: python, regex, string-function

I have to write a single function that should return the first word in the following strings:

```
("Hello world") -> return "Hello"
(" a word ") -> return "a"
("don't touch it") -> return "don't"
("greetings, friends") -> return "greetings"
("... and so on ...") -> return "and"
("hi") -> return "hi"
```

All have to return the first word and as you can see some start with a whitespace, have apostrophes or end with commas.

I've used the following options:

```
return text.split()[0]
return re.split(r'\w*, text)[0]
```

Both error at some of the strings, so who can help me???

Comment: `re.search(r'\w+', text).group()`?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ will return `don` instead of `don't` ;) Try `re.search('[\w\']+', s).group()`

Comment: Try [`r""""[^"\w]*([\w'-]+)"""`](https://regex101.com/r/up15ZL/1)

Comment: @DeepSpace The annoying thing about this question is the arbitrary restrictions with what is to be considered part of a word and what isn't.

Comment: One could use `[\w']+` to find all word-constituents and apostrophes but that would quickly lead to a problem with an input like `"'No!' he shouted"` (`'No` is probably not wanted).

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750265/how-to-get-the-first-word-in-the-string, answered here.

Comment: @DNinja21 Nope, that's not it.

Comment: What about `1 plus 2 gives 3`? Do you want `1` or `plus`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is tricky to distinguish apostrophes which are supposed to be part of a word and single quotes which are punctuation for the syntax.  But since your input examples do not show single quotes, I can go with this:

```
re.match(r'\W*(\w[^,. !?"]*)', text).groups()[0]
```

For all your examples, this works.  It won't work for atypical stuff like `"'tis all in vain!"`, though.  It assumes that words end on commas, dots, spaces, bangs, question marks, and double quotes.  This list can be extended on demand (in the brackets).

Comment: Great!! Thanks for the input!!

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code. I tested with all your inputs and it works fine.

```
import re
text=["Hello world"," a word ","don't touch it","greetings, friends","... and so on ...","hi"]
for i in text:
    rgx = re.compile("(\w[\w']*\w|\w)")
    out=rgx.findall(i)
    print out[0]
```

Output:

```
Hello
a
don't
greetings
and
hi
```

Answer (score 1):

A non-regex solution: stripping off leading punctation/whitespace characters, splitting the string to get the first word, then removing trailing punctuation/whitespace:

```
from string import punctuation, whitespace

def first_word(s):
    to_strip = punctuation + whitespace
    return s.lstrip(to_strip).split(' ', 1)[0].rstrip(to_strip)

tests = [
"Hello world",
"a word",
"don't touch it",
"greetings, friends",
"... and so on ...",
"hi"]

for test in tests:
    print('#{}#'.format(first_word(test)))
```

Outputs:

```
#Hello#
#a#
#don't#
#greetings#
#and#
#hi#
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
>>> def pm(s):
...     p = r"[a-zA-Z][\w']*"
...     m = re.search(p,s)
...     print m.group(0)
...
```

test result:

```
>>> pm("don't touch it")
don't
>>> pm("Hello w")
Hello
>>> pm("greatings, friends")
greatings
>>> pm("... and so on...")
and
>>> pm("hi")
hi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
import re
pattern=r"[a-zA-Z']+"
def first_word(words_tuple):
    match=re.findall(pattern,words_tuple)
    for i in match:
        if i[0].isalnum():
            return i



print(first_word(("don't touch it")))
```

output:

```
don't
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done this by using the first occurrence of white space to stop the "getting" of the first word. Something like this:

```
stringVariable = whatever sentence
firstWord = ""
stringVariableLength = len(stringVariable)
for i in range(0, stringVariableLength):
    if stringVariable[i] != " ":
        firstWord = firstWord + stringVariable[i]
    else:
        break
```

This code will parse through the string variable that you want to get the first word of, and add it into a new variable called firstWord, until it gets to the first occurance of white space. I'm not exactly sure how you would put that into a function as I'm pretty new to this whole thing, but I'm sure it could be done!